# Run jquery function in PHP after data insert

Tags: php, jquery

I have created this php script to insert data in a mysql table. I want to run a jquery function `updatefrm2('name')` after the data has been inserted. How can that be accomplished? This is my code so far:

```
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";
   $dbname = "myDB";

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
           VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
       echo "New record created successfully";
   else
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   $conn->close();
```

Comment: not possible. php runs on the server. javascript(jquery) runs on the client. at MOST you could something like `echo "<script>udpatefrm2('name')</script>"` in php.

Comment: You want to run a Javascript function on completion of a PHP script?

Comment: @MarcB It depends. If the script is being run via an AJAX call in jQuery, it's a whole different ballgame. Need more information. Specifically, how is this script being called?

Comment: I want to run javascript after php insert

Answer (score 0):

If this PHP script is the server side code to the page containing your javascript you can do:

```
<?php echo "<body onload=\"updatefrm2('name');\"> ?>
```

If this is PHP running from an AJAX call then simply return true if updated successfully and check the returned value in your ajax call

```
if(returnedVal == 'true'){ updatefrm2('name'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply echo the `<script>` tag with whatever Javascript you would like to be executed like this :

```
<?php
  echo "<script>updatefrm2('name');</script>";
?>
```